# Determining the correctness of a formal proof

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

Is the following formal proof, proving $\forall A\forall B \forall C[A+C=B+C\Longrightarrow A=B]$ correct??

Proof

1) $a+c=b+c$.............................................................Hypothesis

2)$\neg(a=b)$......................................................................Hypothesis

3)$\forall A\forall B[\neg(A=B\Longrightarrow A<B \vee B<A)]$..........From trichotomy theorem in real Nos

4)$\neg(a=b\Longrightarrow a<b \vee b<a)$.......From (3) and using Universal Elimination  where we put $A=a , B=b$

5)$a<b \vee b<a$................................From (2) & (4) and using Modus Ponens

6)$a<b$.....................................................Hypothesis

7) $\forall A\forall B\forall C[A<B\Longrightarrow A+C<B+C]$................Theorem(Axiom) in real Nos

8)$a<b\Longrightarrow a+c<b+c$......From (7) and using Universal Elimination where we put $A=a,B=b,C=c$

9)$a+c<b+c$....................From (6) & (8) and using Modus Ponens

10)$a+c<a+c$.......................By substituting (1) into (9)

11) $\forall A[\neg(A<A)]$..........................Theorem(Axion) in real Nos

12)$\neg(a+c<a+c)$.......................From (11) and using UE were we put $A=a+c$

13) $\neg(a+c<a+c)\wedge (a+c<a+c)$............From (10) & (12) and using addition introduction

14)$\neg\neg(a=b)$...............................From (2) to (13) and using contradiction

15$a=b$......................................From (14) and using Negation Elimination

16) $a<b\Longrightarrow a=b$

In a similar way we can prove:

17)$b<a\Longrightarrow a=b$

18) $a=b$..................From (5) , (16) , (17) and using Disjunction Elimination

19) $\neg(a=b) \wedge (a=b)$.........................From (2) & (18) and using Addition Introduction

20) $\neg\neg(a=b)$......................................From (2) to (19) and using contradiction

21) $a=b$...............................From (20) and using negation elimination

22) $a+c=b+c\Longrightarrow a=b$........From (1) to (21) and using the law of conditional proof

23) $\forall A\forall B \forall C[A+C=B+C\Longrightarrow A=B]$.................From (22) and using Universal Introduction where we put $a=A,b=B,c=C$

Comment: The *tricotomy law* is uncorrectly written : It is $(a=b ∨ a<b ∨ b<a)$ and thus it must be : $¬a=b \to (a<b ∨ b<a)$

Comment: Steps 19-21 are superfluous... you have already $a=b$ in 18.

Answer (score 0):

If I stopped at line (19) the conclusion would not had been :$a+c<b+c\Longrightarrow a<b$

BUT, $[(a+c<b+c)\wedge (\neg(a<b)]\Longrightarrow a<b$.

Because the hypothesis $ \neg a<b$ had not been discharged yet

This is a simple application of deduction theoerem ( law of conditional proof).

If we assume P and prove Q ,then we have rpoved :**If P, then Q **

And in our case $P$ IS :$[(a+c<b+c)\wedge (\neg(a<b)]$ AND not only $a+c<b+c$

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you ought to specify what your quantifiers range over, in this case real numbers, whether in symbols such as "$\def\rr{\mathbb{R}}$$\forall a,b,c \in \rr\ (\cdots)$" or in words such as "For any reals $a,b,c$".

If you have addition, you presumably have associativity and additive inverse, so the following proof is much cleaner.

Given any $a,b,c \in \rr$ such that $a+c=b+c$:

Let $d \in \rr$ such that $c+d=0_\rr$.

Then $a = a+0_\rr = a+(c+d) = (a+c)+d = (b+c)+d = b+(c+d) = b+0 = b$.